# Add multiple series in Dotnet highcharts asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnethighcharts

at the moment, I can create a series in a dotnet highchart that will display a line on the chart. I am wondering how I'm able to do this with another series. I'm not sure how to add it. 
Here is how I'm creating the first series

```
 Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Incoming Stats" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = stringArr })

            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Amount Incoming" } })
            .SetSeries(new Series { Name = "Incomings", Data = new Data(objectArr) })

            ;
        ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

I basically want to add another series to this - the type of data will be exactly the same. So instead of adding stringArr and ObjectArr, the second time I will add stringArr2 and objectArr2. I'm sure it's a simple answer but I can't find a solution anywhere.
Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the examples at their website:
https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts.Samples/Controllers/DemoController.cs

So basically you just give it an array instead of a single Series.

```
  .SetSeries(new[]
                {
                    new Series { Name = "Tokyo", Data = new Data(ChartsData.TokioData) },
                    new Series { Name = "New York", Data = new Data(ChartsData.NewYorkData) },
                    new Series { Name = "Berlin", Data = new Data(ChartsData.BerlinData) },
                    new Series { Name = "London", Data = new Data(ChartsData.LondonData) }
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively pass through multiple series objects separated by comma.

> Example:

```
 series1.Data = new Data(pointList1.ToArray());
 series2.Data = new Data(pointList2.ToArray());
 chart.SetSeries(new[] { series1, series2 });
```